# How to split css without css-in-js and css modules?

Tags: css, next.js

I have just moved to next.js and I want to create an app with css styles, I don't want to use css-in-js or inline style. Including this, I have seen so far 2 options for me: css modules and global styles imported in _app.js. They are different in this way, simply put:

- css modules are loaded to client only when the components that use them are loaded, they have local scope.
- global styles - loaded all at once, don't have local scope.

I have considered using css modules for loading styles only when needed. However, I faced a problem with overriding styles, specificity issues.
For example, I have a component Button which has icon inside of it, and in its default state, it has certain default look. But Button that I use in navigation may have a bit different look, its icon might be different size etc. In global styles, I would use something like:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <button class="navigation__button button button--modifier">
        <img class="button__icon" />
        <span class="button__text">Click me!</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

...where button, button--modifier, button__icon and button__text are class names for the default styles for Button component, and navigation__button is a class name to adjust the button for navigation, using, for example, inheritance to change icon style as well:

```
.navigation__button .button__icon {
    width: 24px;
}
```

However, using css modules, it can't be overriden in this way if I define the styles in other .module.css file (in our case, in Navigation.module.css). It would need some workaround like using :global selector or adding specificity in other way, but it won't be neat, there will be mess with specificity more and more and in general very complex.

How do devs usually handle this using css modules?
Is it possible somehow to not use css modules but still split the stylesheets, without css-in-js?

Edit: Is there actually a big difference between loading all stylesheets in one bundle, like with global styles, or loading modules in components, in terms of performance or loading speed?

Answer (score 1):

### BEM

- A good class naming convention will allow you to not have to use modules (I see you are already using this)
- [This](https://medium.com/trabe/a-comprehensive-guide-to-using-bem-with-react-14d00c199e0d) is a decent guide to using [BEM naming](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/) convention in React or in your case Next
- You can also have your desired result of being able to define the styles in other files
- Have you also considered using [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) or SCSS?

### SASS / SCSS

- [An Introduction to SASS](https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_intro.php)
- [Examples comparing SASS, SCSS to CSS](https://sass-lang.com/guide/)
- This would allow you to easier have the precision of modules using nesting if you combine this with [BEM naming](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/) without having to manually write it out

As an example in your code (changing class navigation to Navigation assuming you have a Navigation component)

```
<div class="Navigation">
    <button class="Navigation__button Navigation__button--modifier">
        <img class="Navigation__button__icon" />
        <span class="Navigation__button__text">Click me!</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

You could have the SCSS file:

```
.Navigation__button {
  
  // button styling

  &--modifier {
    // modifier styling
  }

  &__icon {
    // icon styling
  }

  &__text {
    // text styling
  }
}
```

### CSS

- If you wish to stick with CSS you could also perhaps use nesting, depending on targeted browsers and versions (see [Can I Use](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/css-nesting/))
- The idea is much the same as above but slightly different syntax [see here](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/css-nesting/)